# connect android device to servlet

Tags: java, android, servlets, ip

I'm building an android application that should  connect to servlet called "Login" in order to verify the user name and the password. It works fine en genyMotion emulator when I use :
    http://192.168.1.100:8081/Android/Login
. But , when I try to connect using my real device , I got time out connection error. I'm using "my wifi router 3.0" to make my laptop hosting my phone. I even tried
    http://192.168.23.1:8081/Android/Login
but still didn't work.
Here's my ipconfig :
[image: ipconfig]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a firewall issue on your system.

Emulator is able to connect because the connection is originating from localhost (same system). However the connection from real device is considered as incoming connection from remote host.

By default windows does not allow any incoming connection from remote host. You change this in firewall setting to allow incoming connections on port 8081.